# Determinant of a random matrix consisting of integers

Tags: programming, matrix

I am trying to implement a function that finds the determinant of a random matrix consisting of integers. This is the code I have written so far, but I am stuck. Suggestions ? I want to find a solution without Det[M].

```
M := RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {8, 8}]

det[M_ /; Dimensions[M][[1]] == Dimensions[M][[2]]] := Module[{i, d},
If[N == 2,
Drop[Mi, {1, 1}, {1, 1}][[1, 1]]*Drop[Mi, {1, 1}, {1, 1}][[2, 2]] -
 Drop[Mi, {1, 1}, {1, 1}][[1, 2]]*
 Drop[Mi, {1, 1}, {1, 1}][[2, 1]], 
For[i = 1, i <= Length[M], i++, 
d = d + (-1)^(1 + i) *M[[1, i]]*
   Minors[Drop[M, {1, 1}, {i, i}], 
      Length[Drop[M, {1, 1}, {i, i}]]][[1]][[1]]]]; 
Return[d, Module]]
det1[Mi_ /; Dimensions[Mi][[1]] == Dimensions[Mi][[2]]] := 
Module[{det1},
det1 = Sum[
If[det1 == 1, 
 Break[], (-1)^(1 + j) *Mi[[1, j]]*det1[Drop[Mi, {1}, {j}]]], {j, 
 1, Length[Mi]}]; Return[det1 // MatrixForm, Module]]
det1[M_ /; Dimensions[M][[1]] == Dimensions[M][[2]]] :=
Module[{i, d = M},
For[i = 1, i <= Length[d], i++,
If[Length[M] == 1, Goto[end]
 If[Length[M] == 2, 
  d = Drop[d, {1}, {1}][[1, 1]]*Drop[d, {1}, {1}][[2, 2]] - 
    Drop[d, {1}, {1}][[1, 2]]*Drop[d, {1}, {1}][[2, 1]]; 
  Goto[end], d = d + (-1)^(1 + i) *d[[1, i]]*Drop[d, {1}, {i}]];
Label[end]; Return[d, Module]]]]
det1[M_ /; Dimensions[M][[1]] == Dimensions[M][[2]]] :=
Module[{i, d = M},
For[i = 1, i <= Length[d], i++,
 Switch[d, 1, Goto[end], 2, 
d = Drop[d, {1}, {1}][[1, 1]]*Drop[d, {1}, {1}][[2, 2]] - 
  Drop[d, {1}, {1}][[1, 2]]*Drop[d, {1}, {1}][[2, 1]]; 
Goto[end], _,
d = d + (-1)^(1 + i) *d[[1, i]]*Drop[d, {1}, {i}]];
 Label[end]; Return[d, Module]]]
Return[Determinant[Mi]]
```

Comment: How about `Det[M]` ?

Comment: I want to find a solution without Det[M]

Comment: Looking at your first attempt, some of the problems are: `N` is undefined (also `N` is a built-in function), `Mi` is undefined, `d` is undefined. `Drop[Mi, {1, 1}, {1, 1}][[1, 1]]` is a very long-winded way to do `Mi[[2, 2]]`. `Return` is unnecessary (just put `d` as the last expression in the module).

Comment: I wont even try to read code with Goto's...

Comment: Question sounds like a homework exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive implementation..

```
  mm = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {#, #}] &@9;
  det[m_?MatrixQ /; (Equal @@ Dimensions@m && Length@m > 1 )] :=
  Sum[
      (-1)^(i + 1) m[[1, i]]
      det[m[[2 ;;, Drop[Range[Length[m]], {i}]]] ] ,
      {i, Length[m]}];
  det[m_List  /; Dimensions[m] == {1, 1} ] := First@First@m
  det[mm] // Timing (* {8.346054, 1259312020} *)
  Det[mm] // Timing (* {0., 1259312020} *)
```

For academic illustration only..

Answer (score 3):

What about using the Leibniz formula?
Here is my approach that should work for any n x n Matrix:

Generate the Matrix:

```
Clear[m];
m = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {4, 4}];
```

Determine its dimension:

```
If[
 Length[Union[Dimensions[m]]] == 1,
 n = Union[Dimensions[m]][[1]]
 ]
```

Determine the permutations for the Leibniz formula:

```
perm = Permutations[
   Range[1, n]
   ];
```

Calculate the determinant:

```
det = Sum[
  Signature[perm[[i]]] * Product[m[[k, perm[[i, k]]  ]], {k, 1, Length[perm[[i]]]}
    ],  {i, 1, Length[perm]}]
```

Done.

Why are you not using the Det-function?

Comment: Im trying to time different approches i have now 3 different methods.

Answer (score 1):

The product of the eigenvalues is equal to the determinant, so you could program:

```
n = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 5}];
Chop[N@Eigenvalues[n] /. List -> Times]
```

Note that

```
Chop[N@Eigenvalues[n] /. List -> Times] == Det[n]
True
```